# Decomposing an ideal using Macaulay2

Tags: ideals, macaulay2

I give Macaulay2 the ideal $I=(y^2, x) \in Q[x , y]$ and then I put `decompose I`. The result is $(x , y)$ but I do not understand why. Does it mean that $I = (x , y)$? but that is not true, because we can not create $y$ in $I$.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.9.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_minimal__Primes.html):

> `decompose` is a synonym for `minimalPrimes`.
>
> This function computes the minimal associated primes of the ideal `I` using characteristic sets. Geometrically, it decomposes the algebraic set defined by `I`.

So $(x,y)$ is the minimal [associated prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime) of $I = (y^2,x)$. (It's just the radical of $I$, since $I$ is a primary ideal.)